# How to interact with the functions of my smart contract in Hardhat?

Tags: solidity, remix, testing, hardhat

I am learning to program in Solidity and have followed a basic tutorial on creating a smart contract from a number counter. The tutorial was followed by using Remix and I was very clear about the structure of the code, the deployment and most importantly the interaction with the functions of my contract through this part of REMIX (next image)

[image]

In this section I can interact with the reading and writing functions of my contract.

Now I am trying to perform the same exercise using Hardhat, as I want to know better the whole process of developing a smart contract. I have been able to create my project as well as write the code of my contract again and compile the contract using the command `npx hardhat compile` but **I do not understand how to perform the deployment (in the blockchain that comes with hardat) and more importantly see the part where I can test the functions that my contract has.**

*From what I have read so far, the process in Hardhat would be to create a test within which I define the calls to my functions and display the results using console.log ()* - **this would be correct, some example link would be appreciated.**

Comment: This might sound like a silly question but did you go through the [Hardhat tutorial](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/)?

Comment: As a side note, I am big fan of Hardhat. I created my own [template](https://github.com/paulrberg/solidity-template/issues), which contains best practices for linting, testing and coverage. You may find it helpful!

Comment: YES I could review that part of the documentation but the closest thing I understood is the testing part, so towards the question since I do not know if there was another way to make the interactions directly with the contract. @PaulRazvanBerg

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to rephrase your question in such a way that it is more specific.

Comment: Ok @PaulRazvanBerg - I going to update my question.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg, I just improved the description of the problem, I hope it is better understood, my question.

Comment: Idk what hardhat ist, but probably truffle is the best place to start learning after remix

Comment: @MajdTL Hardhat is arguably a better development environment than Truffle. It offers features such as multi-solc, mainnet forking and support for TypeScript. It's also extensible - there's a host of community-built plugins that enrich what you can do with Hardhat.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Basically, you need to deploy the contract to your local hardhat net just as you would to any other. That means currently you have to set up a `deploy.js` like in the [official hardhat tutorial](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/deploying-to-a-live-network.html). I'm assuming you followed the official tutorial at least until **Chapter 7: Deploying to a live network** and e.g. `@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers` is already properly installed.

### Preparations

❶ Run:

```
npx hardhat node
```

❷ Open a *new console window* at your project directory. Deploy your smart contract by using the previously mentioned `deploy.js`. You need the `--network` parameter to specify that you want to deploy to localhost.

```bash
npx hardhat run --network localhost scripts/deploy.js
```

The script will throw back some useful information. Keep an eye on the second address (designated by the contract's name) – *you will need it in Step 4*.

❸ Connect to the hardhat console at localhost with:

```bash
npx hardhat console --network localhost
```

❹ Get the ethers.js contract factory and attach to it.

Use the proper name in `getContractFactory()` and paste the address from step 2 in `attach()`

```
const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token")
const token = await Token.attach("0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3")
```

Or in one command:

```
const token = await (await ethers.getContractFactory("Token")).attach("0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3")
```

### Interact with contract

You're in a JavaScript environment. E.g. call the `transfer` method of the hardhat tutorial. For the complete API, [see ethers.js API Docs](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/)

Two more tips:

- Use `await` to avoid `Promise` objects.
- `.toString()` helps you to display `uint256` numbers (which are too big for JS).

For a more detailed read, refer to the excellent [OpenZeppelin tutorial for hardhat](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/learn/deploying-and-interacting?pref=hardhat).

```
> await token.transfer("0xdd2fd4581271e230360230f9337d5c0430bf44c0", 42069)
{
  hash: '0xdc0493ce8ed950b4d4558deb65605ba773067804eacfefd7fc64274a8a805dea',
  ...
> (await token.balanceOf("0xdd2fd4581271e230360230f9337d5c0430bf44c0")).toString()
'42069'
```

Comment: This is very nice. Could you please also add how we may `estimateGas()` for function calls in hardhat?